# Wrapping text on TitleLabel and DetailLabel - Material Card

Tags: ios, swift, cosmicmind

I am using CosmicMind - Material Framework to create a Card. titleLabel and DetailLabel do not wrap to a new line.

My question is: What do I need to do to accomplish such task and is it supposed to be automatically adjusted by the framework?

This is what I have so far:

```
    let card = Card()
    var heartIcon = IconButton()
    heartIcon = IconButton(image: Icon.favoriteBorder, tintColor: Color.red.base)

    //Title Bar
    let toolbar = Toolbar(rightViews: [heartIcon])
    toolbar.title = cardData.cardTitleText
    toolbar.titleLabel.textAlignment = .left
    toolbar.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0

    toolbar.detail = "Company: " + cardData.cardTitleSubtitle
    toolbar.detailLabel.font = RobotoFont.regular(with: 14)
    toolbar.detailLabel.textColor = Color.grey.base
    toolbar.detailLabel.textAlignment = .left
    toolbar.detailLabel.numberOfLines = 0
```

And this is my output:

[image]

**Update:**
I managed to achieve what I wanted by increasing the size of the toolbar frame.

```
toolbar.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width: view.frame.width,height: 100)
```

My goal was to at least show 2 lines of text.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with the CosmicMind framework but usually, `the label.numberOfLines` property defines the maximum number of lines that the label text can have. You can set it to 2 instead of 0 and it should wrap.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Maybe your lineBreakMode is wrong. Try setting `label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping`.

Comment: I managed to get the layout I wanted by increasing the size of the toolbar itself.